# cv2.mouseCallback not registering mouse clicks on cv2 window

Tags: python, computer-vision, mouse, opencv

I am trying to implement a mouse callback function to capture mouse click locations from a window. Below is my code. Despite adding debug messages, the window opens but no mouse clicks are captured. Please take a look. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
detection_boundary = []

def mouse_callback(event, x, y, flags, params):
    global detection_boundary
    if len(detection_boundary) == 4:
        print("Already captured 4 corners of detection boundary!")
    else:
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            print("here")
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            print("Click captured: ", (x,y))
            detection_boundary.append((x,y))

def run:
    #some code
    ...

    #capture detection ROI
    print("To set detection boundary, click on four corners...")
    img  = dataset[0]
    cv2.namedWindow("capturing_detection_boundary")
    cv2.setMouseCallback("capturing_detection_boundary", mouse_callback)
    while len(detection_boundary) <4: 
        cv2.imshow("capturing_detection_boundary", img)
    print("Captured detection boundary!", detection_boundary)
    cv2.destroyWindow("capturing_detection_boundary")
```

Comment: where's the `waitKey`?

Answer (score 0):

Adding waitKey solved the problem. My code for anyone with the same issue:

```
#capture detection ROI
    print("To set detection boundary, click on four corners and press any key")
    img  = dataset[0]
    #img = cv2.resize(img, (1280, 1024))
    cv2.namedWindow("capturing_detection_boundary")
    cv2.setMouseCallback("capturing_detection_boundary", mouse_callback)
    while True: 
        print("Capturing detection boundary.",len(detection_boundary), "clicks captured. Press \'q\' to stop capturing")
        cv2.imshow("capturing_detection_boundary", img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          break
    print("Captured detection boundary!", detection_boundary)
    cv2.destroyWindow("capturing_detection_boundary")
    detection_polygon = Polygon(detection_boundary)
```